# I am have trouble configuring my Django app for Heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have a Django app that runs fine on my local machine so I want to upload it on Heroku

I used the following video to guide me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMbVzl_aLxM

but I am getting the followng error message when I run the following commands `gunicorn core.wsgi`

```
[2020-12-18 02:29:16 +0200] [104166] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-12-18 02:29:16 +0200] [104166] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (104166)
[2020-12-18 02:29:16 +0200] [104166] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-12-18 02:29:16 +0200] [104168] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 104168
[2020-12-18 00:29:16 +0000] [104168] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/snr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Music_Repo-DS3TLAOE/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/snr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Music_Repo-DS3TLAOE/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/snr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Music_Repo-DS3TLAOE/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/snr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Music_Repo-DS3TLAOE/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/snr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Music_Repo-DS3TLAOE/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/snr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Music_Repo-DS3TLAOE/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/snr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Music_Repo-DS3TLAOE/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/snr/My Workspace/Django /Projects/Music Repo/core/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/snr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Music_Repo-DS3TLAOE/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    return WSGIHandler()
  File "/home/snr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Music_Repo-DS3TLAOE/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 127, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/home/snr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Music_Repo-DS3TLAOE/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 40, in load_middleware
    middleware = import_string(middleware_path)
  File "/home/snr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Music_Repo-DS3TLAOE/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djaNot Found: /static/base/css/style'
[2020-12-18 00:29:16 +0000] [104168] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 104168)
[2020-12-18 02:29:16 +0200] [104166] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2020-12-18 02:29:16 +0200] [104166] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Here is my **settings.py** configuration

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent



SECRET_KEY = '*****************************************'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []






INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'repo',
    'users',
    'crispy_forms',
    "bootstrap4",

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'djaNot Found: /static/base/css/style.cssngo.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'core.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'core.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': "****",
        'USER': '****',
        'PASSWORD': '*****',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'repo'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'core.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**Directory structure**

```
Django_project
├── core
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
├── media
│   └── profile_pics
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── Procfilesds
├── repo
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── requirements.txt
├── static
│   ├── admin
│   └── base
└── users
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── forms.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── migrations
    ├── models.py
    ├── signals.py
    ├── tests.py
    └── views.py
```

Comment: In your settings: MIDDLEWARE : 'djaNot Found: /static/base/css/style.cssngo.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', what this ? a missed copy paste ?

Comment: I probably got there by mistake, I removed it and my project now runs fine thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper answer here :

In your settings, you have to remove this line (typo)

```
MIDDLEWARE : 'djaNot Found: /static/base/css/style.cssngo.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
```